# How long does it take Unicorn to respawn a worker after a timeout?

Tags: heroku, unicorn

According to the Unicorn docs:

> The timeout mechanism in Unicorn is an extreme solution that should be avoided whenever possible ... it is expensive as it kills and respawns a worker process.

How expensive is it, and how would I go about measuring that cost?

Backstory: I have an app on Heroku using the default Unicorn config (preloaded; timeout 15s.) I'm curious as to how long it takes Unicorn to spin up a new worker after a timeout, because if it's on the order of seconds it might make sense to raise the timeout *above* Heroku's 30s cutoff. That way the worker has a bit of grace time to complete something like a particularly large image upload (even if the response never delivered to the client) and free itself up without the overhead of a respawn.

On the other hand, if respawning happens on the order of milliseconds then it's presumably always cheaper to simply throw a timeout and get a fresh worker.